# "Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed" error even though JDK is installed

Tags: apt, java, jdk, oracle

I installed Java Jdk manually by downloading jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz and following [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux). When I check its version, it's OK:

```
user@mylaptop:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

But when I try to install pip by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

or input something like this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get this error:

```
user@mylaptop:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pip is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu-extra libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libgconf2-4 libgnome2-0
  libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libice-dev
  libidl-common libidl0 liborbit-2-0 liborbit2 libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev
  libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev
  tzdata-java x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 476 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u76+7u60arm-0~webupd8~0) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2015-02-01 05:55:03--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u76-b13/jdk-7u76-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 93.158.110.104, 93.158.110.115
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|93.158.110.104|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2015-02-01 05:55:12 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

)

Can you tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have webupd8's `oracle-java7-installer`  installed in your system which is trying to install oracle java by downloading it from Oracle site. Oracle website is restricting your access, and that is why you are getting this error.

If you have installed Java manually, you can remove  `oracle-java7-installer`.

Run following command to fix it.

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It should solve the dpkg error.